# C++: How to read large txt file and save to array faster

Tags: c++, arrays, multithreading, file-io, profiling

I want to read a large txt file which has more than 50000 lines.

sample of the files:

```
John 12 1 956 02 818 912 322 43 161 9 002 768 23 79 9 1 115 7 2 18 59 58 989 3 56 82 59 147 86 62 06 10 538 36 694 952 71 0 2 5 67 103 6 295 933 428 9 70 708 6 73 449 57 283 6 48 139 5 140 34 5 9 95 74 892 9 387 172 44 05 67 534 7 79 5 565 417 252 480 22 503 089 76 433 93 36 374 97 035 70 2 896 0 3 0 259 93 92 47 860
```

**description:** 
Above sample is each line in the txt file. each character and string are divided by space.

**The goal:** 
I want to save the value of integer after the first word (in this case: John) and save to a Intager Matrice whose row = **number of line in the txt file** and column = 100.

**Here is my code**

```
Mat readInteger(String path_txt_file){  
int row = 1;
int col = 100;
Mat return_mat;

Mat tmp_mat= Mat(row, col, CV_32F);

fstream input(path_txt_file);
for (std::string line; getline(input, line);)
{
    int posMat = -1;
    vector<string> v = split<string>(line, " ");
    for (int i = 1; i < v.size(); i++)
    {   
        posMat = posMat + 1;
        tmp_mat.at<float>(0, posMat) = atoi(v[i].c_str()); //white  
    }
    return_mat.push_back(tmp_mat);
}
tmp_mat.release();
return return_mat;
}
```

**Code description**

1. I followed the classical way of reading the data from txt file is
   read line by line
2. I created two Mat, return_mat and tmp_mat
3. Each time for each line
   tmp_mat whose row = 1 and col = 100 is used to store integer each line 
   then we split string according to whitespace
   after that we push the whole tmp_mat to return_mat.

**Result**
I got the result I want; **unfortunately**, when the file is too big (and we need that). The process is too slow.

**Question**

**How can we improve this algo. to deal with large file 1000000 lines for instance?
I wonder if we should use multithreading?**

Thank

Comment: 1Mio times that line is 319MB, depending on the data types in the program even more. ... How slow is "too slow"? Multithreading with one text file...? Hmm... (allocatin vectors each line etc. is *bad*)

Comment: "How slow": it is more than two hours and still read from the file.

Comment: have you considered using binary files? Then you can read the whole array with a single read instruction, but have to to know the size of your array/vector beforehand

Comment: nice suggestion that is one option that m testing right now..

Comment: Muktithreading is not the magic bullet that solves all perf Problems. If the disk is the bottleneck, no threadpool will help. I'd recommend (a) using a **profiler**, then (b) improve bottlenecks. Without testing, I'd suspect the I/O operation being the slowest part, thus some kind of buffering (or using MMF) may bring a remarkable boost.

Comment: That seems astonishingly slow. A 300mb file should not really take that long to load and parse. Couple more quick suggestions: Use the normal `cin >>` process to populate each row of the matrix, instead of building a string, splitting the string into a vector, converting each element and then destroying the vector. Also make sure that `return_mat` has preallocated enough memory to store the whole dataset. Finally, you might consider memory-mapped files, though I don't know how useful they'd be here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you have any say on how the original file is constructed but you could suggest some changes.
I don't think the reading is slow but all the casting is.
You first split the line which is slow and then you first cast it to an integer and then again to a float. Also you use the Mat.at function and as far as I know that isn't to fast either (could be wrong on that).
Also pushing back a row to another mat is the same as doing a copy which takes time.
It's not a lot but it cumulates over time with big files.

My suggestion is the following:

Create a struct looking like this:

```
struct Data
{
    char[100] FirstWord;
    std::array<int, 100> Data;
}
```

Instead of creating a text file, you use a binary file and write this struct to it. (just look into writing to binary files: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/write/)

If you read the file again in you can do something like this:

```
ifstream file ("File.dat", ios::in|ios::binary);
if (file.is_open())
{
    Data D;
    file.read(reinterpet_cast<char*>(&D), sizeof(D));
    Mat A(RowSize,ColSize,D.data());
}
```

In this way you don't need to do all the casting. You just need 1 copy.

Hope this helps